# Flex 4.5 turn off globally all objects drop shadows and special fx's and increasing performance?

Tags: apache-flex, performance, dropshadow

- Is there any way to turn off all special FX's and especially dropShadow's on all objects inside the application ?

( The idea is to increase the performance , another ideas on increasing preformance is more than appreciated. )

Comment: I think you'll have to create a custom theme for drop shadows and stuff.  But, What special effects are you referring to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should look into [Flex 4 theming](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf69084-7f85.html) to remove anything that you want/don't want.  By default the Spark theme is used for a Flex project.  Look into your project's properties and change it around.  I believe there are some themes in Flash Builder that doesn't have shadows.

Answer (score 2):

You need to override a lot of skin files or use (or create) a custom theme. Flex does a lot of drawing in its skins... for instance the default Spark TextInput draws a 1px shadow inside the text box. It does NOT use the "dropShadow" filter to do this.

Overriding skin files is easy to do and you can make them defaults in your CSS like this:

```
s|TextInput{
    skinClass: ClassReference("you.com.view.skins.LookMaNoShadowTextInputSkin");
}
```

Comment: Not particularly true.  You could if you're using the default Spark theme, but you could just as easily change the theme to something without without drop shadows.

Comment: you're right, I meant to say "custom theme" instead of skin in the first sentence. Edited